# I'm a beginner and can't install some specific packages on PyCharm (M2 MacOS Ventura), I'm getting errors

Tags: python, macos, package, pycharm

The command and following error:

```
(venv) user@Users-Air VIRTUAL INTERVIEW % source /Users/user/Downloads/VIRTUAL INTERVIEW/venv/bin/activate
pip install MeCab==0.996.3
source: no such file or directory: /Users/user/Downloads/VIRTUAL
Collecting MeCab==0.996.3
  Using cached mecab-0.996.3.tar.gz (62 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mecab-config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/wv/x5b4jqk542lcfctckpt1dkch0000gn/T/pip-install-8u_gf6tb/mecab_3d4bee3e91b04c7fad7d04ba20e36dce/setup.py", line 53, in <module>
          include_dirs=cmd2("mecab-config --inc-dir"),
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wv/x5b4jqk542lcfctckpt1dkch0000gn/T/pip-install-8u_gf6tb/mecab_3d4bee3e91b04c7fad7d04ba20e36dce/setup.py", line 19, in cmd2
          return cmd1(strings).split()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wv/x5b4jqk542lcfctckpt1dkch0000gn/T/pip-install-8u_gf6tb/mecab_3d4bee3e91b04c7fad7d04ba20e36dce/setup.py", line 15, in cmd1
          return os.popen(strings).readlines()[0].rstrip()
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
      IndexError: list index out of range
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried just clicking the default button PyCharm provides to install packages, but I got an error and it recommended I run that command in the terminal, and thats the result.

Comment: The first error: `source /Users/user/Downloads/VIRTUAL INTERVIEW/venv/bin/activate` : you have am unquoted space, so macox and any unix think VIRTUAL is a file/directory, and the rest is an additional parameter

Answer (score 0):

Mecab does not provide wheel (prebuild binary) for MacOS at all and the package relies on external mecab to be installed (at least on mac)

Do you have homebrew ?  If yes

```bash
brew install mecab
pip install MeCab==0.996.3
```

might do the trick.

EDIT:

There's also https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/ that does ship mac/arm wheels. Using that could be an alternative if homebrew is not available.